# "\Ualgocf@original@chapter" undefined when using algorithm2e with natbib

Tags: natbib, incompatibility, algorithm2e

Is it possible to just use `plainnat` without using the package `natbib`? When I do so, multiple author references don't work too well. I get

> [author et al (year)auhtor1, author2 and author3]

when what I want is just

> [author et al (year)]

Anyway to fix this?

If I add `\usepackage{natbib}` I just get an error:

```
Undefined control  sequence.

\chtapter ...ace {10\p@ }}\algocf@original@chapter

1.1 \begin{thebibliography}{28}
```

So using `plainnat` without `natbib` is the closest I got to get this working.

Example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{babelbib,url} 
\usepackage{breakcites}
%\usepackage{natbib}
%\usepackage[square, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pslatex}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{2} 
\begin{document}
    \cite{DPS2000}
\newpage\pagebreak
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

It compiles fine but I get

> [author et al (year)auhtor1, author2 and author3]

style referencing and if I uncomment `natbib` it won't compile.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that the `algorithm2e` expects `\chapter` to be defined. It makes some changes to how the bibliography is printed which do not make sense. One fix is to do

```
\let\chapter\section
```

before loading `algorithm2e`: the problem should be go away.

Answer (score 8):

Load `algorithm2e` *after* `natbib`.