# Problem compiling LaTeX file created on Linux

Tags: bibtex, mactex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“\Ualgocf@original@chapter” undefined when using algorithm2e with natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14938/ualgocforiginalchapter-undefined-when-using-algorithm2e-with-natbib)

I have a TeX file created on Linux, and I'm trying to compile it on Mac OS X but I'm having a weird error in the bibliography.

```
[11] [12] [13] (./test-tex.bbl ! Undefined control sequence.
\chapter ...ace {10\p@ }}\algocf@original@chapter 
   l.1 \begin{thebibliography}{5}
```

I tried TeXworks and TeXShop but it did not work with both.
I also tried to remove the `.aux` file but also no luck.

When I remove the bibliography section the file compiles normally.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: Possibly related to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14938/plainnat-bst-without-natbib

Comment: yes exactly, this sloved my problem. but wasnt finding this thread since the title is not related to what i'm searching for. how can i give you upvote ??

Comment: can we vote to close as a duplicate?

Comment: I simply googled `\algocf@original@chapter` and that question was the first hit.