# KOMA-Script article in LyX

Tags: table-of-contents, lyx, koma-script, document-classes

I would like to set the document class of my LyX document to KOMA-Script article. When I try this via `Document > Settings > Document Class`, the document does not compile any more. Last part of Error message:

```
Package amsthm Warning: Unknown theoremstyle `slplain' on input line 158.

(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/preprint/fullpage.sty)
(./KOMA.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
(./KOMA.out) (./KOMA.out)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1cmss.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
./KOMA.tex:181: Undefined control sequence.
\chapter ...ace {10\p@ }}\algocf@original@chapter 

l.181 \tableofcontents
                      {}
? 
(./KOMA.toc) [1{/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdfte
x.map}] (./KOMA.aux) ){/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/cm-su
per/cm-super-t1.enc}</usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-s
uper/sfrm1000.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-sup
er/sfrm1440.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super
/sfsx2074.pfb>
Output written on KOMA.pdf (1 page, 27879 bytes).
SyncTeX written on KOMA.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on KOMA.log.
```

What is wrong with the TOC here? Why is it not compatible with the document class?

EDIT: As requested, here is a minimal example for which the error appears:

```
%% LyX 2.0.5.1 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[10pt,english]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
%------------------- My Packages --------------------------
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\usepackage[ruled,vlined, linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{shadethm}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{soul} % text highlighting
%\usepackage{minted} % code
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
%\usepackage{mparhack}
\usepackage{rotating}
%\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{numprint}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage[switch]{lineno}
\usepackage{balance}


%----------------- My Settings ------------------------------

\DeclareGraphicsRule{.tif}{png}{.png}{`convert #1 `dirname #1`/`basename #1 .tif`.png}
\graphicspath{{graphics/}}


%------------------- My Commands --------------------------


% text formatting
\newcommand{\algo}[1]{\textsf{#1}}
\newcommand{\term}[1]{\emph{#1}}
\newcommand{\atitle}[1]{\textsl{#1}}
\newcommand{\func}[1]{ \mathit{#1} }
\newcommand{\var}[1]{\mathtt{#1}}
\newcommand{\name}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\newcommand{\software}[1]{\textsf{#1}}
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\textsf{#1}}
\newcommand{\class}[1]{\textsf{#1}}
\newcommand{\method}[1]{\textsf{#1}}
\newcommand{\prb}[1]{\textsc{{\small#1}}}
\newcommand{\smallcaption}[1]{\caption{\scriptsize{#1}}}



% symbols
\newcommand{\NP}{$\mathcal{N}\mathcal{P}$}
\newcommand{\auth}{\smile}
\newcommand{\coauth}{\frown}
\newcommand{\mb}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\orp}{\; | \;}
\newcommand{\AND}{\wedge}

% notes 
\newcommand{\vertical}[1]{\begin{sideways}#1\end{sideways}}
\newcommand{\TODO}[1]{\todo[size=\small, inline]{#1}}
\newcommand{\tinytodo}[1]{\todo[size=\tiny, inline]{#1}}
\newcommand{\note}[1]{\textcolor{orange}{\textbf{#1}}}

% abbreviations
\newcommand{\pairs}[1]{\textstyle{#1 \choose 2}}
\newcommand{\set}[1]{ \{ #1 \} }
\newcommand{\fig}[1]{Fig.~\ref{#1}}
%\newcommand{\ie}{i.e.\ }
%\newcommand{\eg}{e.g.\ }
%\newcommand{\etal}{et\! al.\! }

\newcommand{\ie}{i.\,e.,\xspace}
\newcommand{\eg}{e.\,g.,\xspace}
\newcommand{\etal}{et al.\xspace}
\newcommand{\Wlog}{w.\,l.\,o.\,g.\ }
\newcommand{\wrt}{w.\,r.\,t.\xspace}


% other
\newcommand{\margindef}[1]{\marginpar{\textsf{{\scriptsize #1}}} } % margin definition in small caps

\newcommand{\defblock}[2]{\begin{definition} \margindef{\\ #1}#2 \end{definition}} % definition block with margin definition


\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{paragraph}{section}
\makeatother

% ------------------- My Environments ---------------------

\newenvironment{citemize}{
\begin{itemize}
  \setlength{\itemsep}{1pt}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
}{\end{itemize}
}

\newenvironment{fitemize}{
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\small$\circ$}
\begin{itemize}
  \setlength{\itemsep}{1pt}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
}{\end{itemize}
}


\newenvironment{termdef}[2][default]
{\margindef{\\ #2} Def.: \textbf{#2} \\}
{}


\newenvironment{noteblock}{
\color{orange} }
{}


%------ This set of macros generates the daytime and puts it to the footline
\newcount\shortyear\newcount\shorthour\newcount\shortminute
\shorthour=\time\divide\shorthour by 60\shortyear=\shorthour
\multiply\shortyear by 60\shortminute=\time\advance\shortminute by
-\shortyear
\shortyear=\year\advance\shortyear by -1900

\def\zeit{\number\shorthour:\ifnum\shortminute<10 0\number\shortminute
\else\number\shortminute\fi}

\def\rightmark{{\small \today, \zeit{}}}
%\def\rightmark{}    %<-- Uncomment this line to remove the daytime!
%------




%------------ My Theorems --------------------


\theoremstyle{slplain}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{definition}{Def.}


% My Packages

\usepackage{fullpage} % smaller page margins

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{Title}


\author{Author}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}
\tableofcontents{}

\pagebreak{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\tableofcontents` works just fine in KOMA's article class, so there must be something else wrong. Can you trim the LyX file down to the minimum showing the problem, and include either the `.lyx` file (it is just plain text, as you'll see if you open it in a text editor) or the exported LaTeX source?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I have added the exported LaTeX source.

Comment: Works just fine here, compiled with pdfLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. So the corresponding LyX file gives that error? Don't know what could cause that. If you open the `.tex` file in e.g. TeXworks and compile with pdfLaTeX (choose it from the drop down on the top left, and click the green arrow), does it work?

Comment: @TorbjørnT.  I use TeXshop. Compiling halts on an error, which I can ignore by pressing return. Then a PDF is produced which does not have a proper TOC. It also shows me a more complete error message, see my updated post. Unfortunately I cannot understand it.

Comment: Right, so it's `\algocf@original@chapter` that is undefined, not `\tableofcontents`. I don't know exactly why it occurs, probably from an algorithm-related package. I have TeX Live 2013, so perhaps updating to MacTeX 2013 would solve the problem. Note also the warning, that there is no theoremstyle called `slplain`, so I guess `\theoremstyle{slplain}` wont have any effect.

Comment: This appears to happen because `algorithm2e` expects `\chapter` to be available, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14938/ualgocforiginalchapter-undefined-when-using-algorithm2e-with-natbib (and http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=14049). As the error didn't occur for me I would guess that this has been fixed in the package recently.  You could try `\let\chapter\section` before `\usepackage{algorithm2e}`, if you haven't already upgraded MacTeX.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. This works as a temporary solution.